# Что значит название "Волга"?

Tags: этимология, топонимика

Каково происхождение название реки "Волга" и что означает это слово?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Название реки Волга происходит от старославянского "вълга" - "влага", "сырость", "вода".
Древние названия реки: Ра, Итиль.

Answer (score 1):

Название реки волга от осетино-сарматского ИВЫЛГА - означает разливающая без края, что отражает сущность этой реки как предыдущие название РА и ИТИЛЬ по осетино-сарматский означают ДУРНАЯ река.Также все реки юга России ДОН, ДНЕПР, ДНЕСТР, ДУНАЙ имеют осетино-сарматское происхождение!

Answer (score 1):

skif, не совсем. Дунай - Русское название реки восходит к праслав. *Dunajь, которое было заимствовано через готск. *Dōnawi из кельтск. Dānuvius.

Волга - Происходит от праслав. *Vьlga, ср. во́лглый, польск. wilgoć «влажность», с другой ступенью чередования: русск. воло́га, ст.-слав. влага (ср. интонацию: -оло́- и Во́лга, а не *Волга́); ср.: чешск. Vlha — река бассейна Лабы, польск. Wilga — река бассейна Вислы. Из *Повьлжье или *Повължье произошло др.-русск. Поволожье (Новгор. I летоп.), ср. во́ложка.

Это основная версия из любого этимологического словаря

Comment: Волгой , вообще-то , по крайней мере , в её нижней части изначально владели хазары . Потом появилась Волжская Булгария , которая во многом была связана с Хазарией . Логичнее поискать этимологию в иврите=хазарском или в тюркском=булгарском .

Comment: @АлексейМорозов согласен. Беда вот только что кок-кому словари - не указ. Надо искать какие-то хазарские корни, лишь бы шпильку вставить. Беда вот только, что у Волги столько названий, что народов не хватит. И что, все их, корни названий, искать у хазарейцев?

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте все книги чувашского историка и филолога Геннадия П. Егорова, которые выходили с 1992гг., о кочевых племенах сувар (шумеров) язык которых исходит к 5000-8000 лет до нашей эры. Язык сувар передался без изменения их потомкам чувашам, о чем скрывает история. Чувашский язык мягкий и глухими согласными, вместо б, г, д, з читается п,к,т,с. Название реки Волга (русские историки дали произношение по русски) произошло от слова названия одного из главных городов Волжской Булгарии Булгар. Заменяя чувашскими глухими согласными получаем Во(у)лкар.Буква "о" это европейское произношение, "у" это тюркское.  Кар(та) по чувашски означает укрепление, изгородь, ограда. Названия городов Йошкарола, Сыктывкар, Щупашкар (Чебоксары).  В итоге ВОЛГА. Буквы у и р убрали, а г оставили, т.к. легче и звонче произносится.   А то могло звучать другое слово ВОЛК(А), дикий зверь волк. А зверь волк ассоциируется у тюрков ещё другой древней историей, легендой.                             Если захочется ещё у какого-то другого слова,  понять происхождение, обратитесь к истокам Чувашского языка, там найдете историю, объяснение на уровне филологии, как меняется звучание переход с одног языка на другой.